# How to connect active neo4j db from java (without REST API )?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have installed neo4j version 1.9.5 and tried some java sample to access / write data into graphdb, but for every action the existing graph db instance is created newly using below,
`graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("c:/movies/moviesdb");` so is it possible to access and execute cypher query through java on active Neo4j db without REST API concept.

Note : Consider Ne04j DB is already started and running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running Neo4j as a server process, you communicate with your DB only via REST. The other usage model is embedded. Here you're application code controls the lifecycle of the DB by using `new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase()`. These two modes are distinct.

Comment: I saw a deprecated method called "remoteshell" will this able to communicate a running DB instead of REST ?

Comment: the remote shell is intended to be used for maintenance but not for really using Neo4j in a performant way. In case you want to talk to Neo4j on Java API level, but you still want to run as a server, consider using unmanaged extensions: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html